# Cannot declare a class template with no name

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, clang++

The error:

> "cannot declare a class template with no name"

is given by clang++ with the following file, "foo.cpp":

```cpp
#ifndef foo
#define foo

template <class T>
struct foo {
private:
    const T t;
};

#endif
```

The command line input and error:

```
me@computer$ clang++ -c foo.cpp
foo.cpp:5:1: error: cannot declare a class template with no name
```

Comment: Do you know what a preprocessor does? After your first two lines in the file, imagine *every* symbol `foo` being substituted with... what was `foo` defined to be again? Oh yeah... *nothing*.

Comment: You are quite the magician.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the include guards. They define `foo` to be nothing, replacing any further occurrence of `foo` with nothng. This removes your class template's name.

```
#ifndef FOO_H_
#define FOO_H_

// as before

#endif
```